# Firestore query with order stability

Tags: firebase, sorting, google-cloud-firestore

In Firebase Firestore, if I query the database by order (i.e. ascending order of number), even if the numbers may not be unique, will the order be stable?

By the word 'stable', I meant by: If I query the same query many times without updating and the result is ordered the same, then it's stable.

Querying in order is referenced from [the Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data).

Answer (score 0):

Firestore guarantees a stable ordering through the following rules:

Any field required to appear in orderBy, that is not already specified in orderBy, is appended to the order in field name order by default.
If an order on **name** is not specified, it is appended by default.

More details: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/StructuredQuery